# Accessing iTunes Top Songs

Tags: ios, objective-c, itunes

I am writing an iOS application that alerts the user what the top 10 songs on iTunes are on a monthly basis. What is the best way of accessing the iTunes top songs list? Should I use PHP? Or something else? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would probably to use Apple's [RSS](http://itunes.apple.com/rss) page to access the content you need. A simple [RSS/XML parser](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for iOS is then enough to do whatever you want with that data.